# How to use a variable created inside a function, outside of the function? (Android Studio, Java)

Tags: android, function, variables, calendar

[image]

I have this function which create a calendar alert dialog.
Now, I want to use the 'date' (which I marked) outside of the function but I cant figure out how to do it. Ill be happy to get suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you need it in the same class you need an instance variable.

Example:

```
public class Sample extends AppCompatActivity
{
    String date;

    //rest of your code

}
```

On your function use only your variable without declaration.

Example:

```
 date=month+"/"+day+"/"+year;
```